# Hide empty folders in a particular view sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, document-library, view, folder

I have a document library in my SharePoint site. It has structure like this :

- Year Folder

  - Month Folder

    - Document Set

      - Document

I have applied my filter condition and created a new view for that. Now the problem is even if the folders are empty in that view they are visible. I want to remove these empty folders. How to solve this issue, since its not user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

In the view filter properties, you can select property `Folder Child Count` and use that as

```
Folder Child Count > 0
```

Comment: I have already tried that.It doesn't work. It counts the folder child for "all documents" view of library, not my view.

Answer (score 0):

In the view filter properties, select property **Item Child Count** (which means the number of items inside the folder) **is greater than** **0**.